# Consuming Vista .NET Localhost Webserices Over Wifi Network From Mac iPhone Project

Tags: asp.net, iphone, web-services, localhost, wifi

I have SQL Server Express and Visual Studio Web Developer Express running on my PC.  In visual studio I created a web service that runs on the localhost.

On my Mac I have an iPhone application that consumes the web service.  Can I connect to the PC's localhost web service inside my iPhone application?  What would the URL to the web service on the PC be (http://localhost:49973/BaseballWebService/Service.asmx)?

Big thanks already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Localhost means localhost. Another computer is never the localhost. Use it's IP or give it a name.

Comment: Thanks NSD.  That makes sense.  How would I create the local network or sharing?  Is it created by the PC?